# SQL Server stored procedure restores to previous one

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

There's a Stored Procedure in my database which keeps restoring to the old one, I `Alter` the stored procedure using Management Studio, however some time later, unexpectedly, the stored procedure changes to the one before `Alter`! This has happened several times during past hours!

I am certain that nowhere inside the program or manually I change the Stored Procedure. I checked all Agent Jobs, There's only one `Maintenance job` for hourly backup, and another one for `Replication`, however `Replication Schema Changes` is set to `false`, and Stored Procedures are **not** defined in the list of `Publication Articles`

Is there any other possible reason for this behavior? Do I need to manually set a CHECKPOINT in the SQL Server database?

Comment: just guessing here, but did you search all you proc or app code to see if it is doing any of it?  mabe something is scripted somewhere and it just keeps altering it back to the original.

Comment: Limey: Yes, I do not use any sort of script or ADO connection to change database

Comment: Is it happening more often that your hourly backup?  can you track its status before and after your hourly job runs?

Comment: No, it happens in, say, 2 to 3 hours intervals!

Comment: can you turn on logging and see if any other alter commands come thru?

Comment: Alternative and longer answer at http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33544/18421

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a DDL trigger to log `ALTER_PROCEDURE` events like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AlterLog(EventType VARCHAR(50)
, ObjectName VARCHAR(256)
, ObjectType VARCHAR(25)
, TSQLCommand VARCHAR(MAX)
, LoginName VARCHAR(256)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AlterProcs
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_PROCEDURE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO dbo.AlterLog(EventType, ObjectName, ObjectType, TSQLCommand, LoginName)
VALUES(@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
)
GO
```

Comment: Thank you John, I didn't know, Trigger works for Database! I used the trigger, and turns out it was the Publication database that kept changing my Stored Procedure whenever Replication Agent is running! The Publication DBA had told us that no Schema Changes are being replicated, obviously he is wrong. thanks again

Comment: See also similar answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33541/how-to-keep-history-of-sql-server-stored-procedure-revisions