# How to keep history of SQL Server stored procedure revisions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, version-control

Note: I am not asking about full version control.

Is there any way automatically to keep a history of stored procedures on SQL Server.

Similar to how Google Docs automatically keeps a history of versions of documents and Wikipedia automatically keeps a history of versions of articles.

I don't want users updating stored procedures to have also to maintain a repository of stored procedures. This is too much work and people won't do it.

Hopefully this is something I can turn on in SQL Server...

(And by stored procedures really I mean functions, triggers, etc. Basically everything under Programmability.)

Comment: Completely tanked a stored procedure just two days ago, spent twelve hours rewriting, there was no backup or revision. MSSQL _needs_ this.

Comment: @GrantThomas: Store the script for the stored procedure in Dropbox, and you won't have that problem.  Dropbox can even go back to old revisions of a file, in case you `ctrl-a` `del` `ctrl-s`.

Comment: @GrantThomas "there was no backup ... MSSQL needs this" I think you'll find you need backups.

Comment: The source code for stored procedures has to go into a version control system (subversion, git, ...) just as you do for Java or C# code. Not asking for "full version control" is wrong, you do need it.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Automated backup was the first thing I configured post-fix.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My replies to your comment at the time have been deleted. What I said was that where I was working at the time the development team didn't want to use an external VCS and that anyway, version control built into the database would be more foolproof. Better to help developers than to tell them what they need and what has to happen. A multi-layered approach would be best - external VCS and internal version control.

Comment: This might help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/ddl-data-sources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this might help: [SQL Server stored procedure restores to previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820024/sql-server-stored-procedure-restores-to-previous-one?rq=1)

But surely this is built in or can be implemented via some plugin that already exists...

Answer (score 3):

You could run [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) every hour to write all definitions to a disk.  If the same job commits that directory to source control, you get an hourly history of the database.

You can also use [RedGate SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/), but that requires everyone to commit manually.

Comment: I want the trigger to be a change, not a timer.